# CSharpAPI.sln does not build solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, solution, visual-studio-express

I'm currently learning how to integrate APIs into my program, writing in C#. For this, I am following a tutorial based on Visual Studio 2010, using the tutorial provided here:

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/csharp/csharpsampleapptutorial.htm

And the API itself is available here:

http://interactivebrokers.github.io/

Now my problem is at step 3, where I have to build a solution from the CSharpAPI.sln-file. I open it up in Visual Studio, navigate to "Build Solution" and then I get the following output from the build:

> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>
> This does not yield the .dll-file I need. The output I need is for it
>   to declare "1 succeeded" and compile the .dll-file to
>   "/source/csharpclient/bin/Release"

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

Comment: Have you tried the `Rebuild` option?

Comment: it says the project output is up to date. Have you tried `Build -> Rebuild Solution` rather than just `Build`?

Comment: Btw, if the project is `up-to-date` normally there is no need for a rebuild. It means that there were no changes so there is no need for a rebuild. Although there are some rare exceptions.

Comment: I just tried running the `Build -> Rebuild Solution` method now. It generates a file named "TWSLib.dll" under **F:\TWS API\source\csharpclient\bin\Debug\** (I have my files stored to the F-drive). But I need it to generate .dll-file from CSharpAPI.sln to **F:\TWS API\source\csharpclient\bin\Release** named "CSharpAPI.dll" But does "TWSLib.dll" in the debug folder contain the same information as the one I'm trying to generate? I'm not overly familiar with this whole process.

Answer (score -2):

Right click Visual Studio to "Run as Administrator".